# Linking two collections from mongoDB with vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, npm

Hi I am new to using vue and mongodb. I have two collections created one for user details and the other for business details. The business registers on a form then is stored in mongodb. For the user I have created a form but i want the business names from the business collection to display on the form so the user can choose it. I am unsure how to link two collections ?

[Front End Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MjFN.png)

[Booking Model Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5aTI.png)

[Organisation Model Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4kXH.png)

Comment: Provide more information like, code sample, what package you use for mongodb? is it mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using MONGOOSE, you can do it with ref

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var businessSchema = Schema({
    name : String,
});

var userSchema = Schema({
    businessDetails: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business' },
    gender: {type: String, enum: ["Male", "Female"]},
    city: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', eventSchema);
var Business = mongoose.model('Business', personSchema);

function getUserDetails (callback) {
   User.find().populate({'businessDetails'}).callback()
}
```

Here you will get data like

```
[
   {
      businessDetails: {
                            name: "Harshal",
                            gender: "Male",
                            city: "Pune"
                        }
   }
]
```

Now you can display on UI as you want.

Comment: In my Booking form i am trying too display the organisation names that are stored in one of my mongodb collections instead of hard coding the organisation names in. But the booking form will also be stored in mongodb.